# SQL Update row from select Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am trying to use a `Select` statement to update a column in a table.

I am trying to copy the letters before @ in the the `email column into the`Initials` column.

This keeps failing

```
SELECT        UserID, Username, Email, FullName, Initials
FROM            Users
set Initials = (select left(Email, charindex('@', Email + '@')-1)
```

I am very new to SQL so please bear with me, if i am making obvious mistakes.

Comment: You could find all what you need **[`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and also a very good examples.

Comment: Please find the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf68e8b3e52b3127ea1d0b24c69cd771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below -

```
update Users
     set Initials = left(Email, charindex('@', Email + '@')-1)
```

Comment: I get the following error :Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @RenéIversen, what is your data length for initial column? It seems you need to increase the size of data length for this columns

Comment: @RenéIversen I suggest you edit your question to include a sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

update Users
     set Initials = left(Email, charindex('@', Email + '@')-1)
     where len(Initials)>= len(left(Email, charindex('@', Email + '@')-1))